# Website domain gets a warning "Deceptive Site Ahead" and is blocked by Google

Tags: wordpress, google-search-console, malware-detection

The website was tagged as deceptive site but we already did a malware check and cleaned the website files at the same time. We also requested a review from Google so they could remove our website from their blacklist. However, on the deceptive site warning, when I click the link that says "ignore the risk" (I'm using firefox on this and on chrome it says 'visit this unsafe site'), the domain is routed on a page that looks like selling clothes or rather an advertisement, it is not routed on the webpage that it should be. Is this a problem on its hosting or is there any way to fix this? I am still waiting for Google's feedback though on the review request I sent 3 days ago.

Comment: Hi Annabeth. Did you solve your issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, I can suggest you to wait at least 7 days before Google send you feedback and if you really done cleaning malware code from your site, that notice will be postponed by this time.

Comment: Aside from waiting, Is there anything that we could do on its hosting side?

Comment: If you already sent review requests to Google than its all up to Google to crawl your site soon as it come and remove malware flag.